# Validate CSS 'backgroud-image' URL using Cypress

Tags: javascript, vue.js, cypress

I am trying to validate if the CSS 'backgroud-image' URL has status code '200'. Is it possible to validate loading of images using Cypress. Can anyone please suggest?

```
it('Validate the images displayed',() => {
    cy.get('.logo').each(($el,index,$list) => {
        expect($el).to.have.css('background-image','*should pass dynamic url image*')     
    })
```

Comment: What does your image url look like ?

Comment: The image comes from a CMS and it looks like: background-image: url(https://abc.abc.ca/ImageProvider/Sprite?seoid=nba&size=48);
}

Comment: And what do you mean when you say `validate loading of images using Cypress`. Do you mean to check that all your image links return 200 then you can go with @agoff's answer or are you looking for something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you get the element, you can use a JQuery function to return the `background-image` css value (`$el.css('css-property')`), and use that in a `cy.request()` function where you validate it is a 200.

```js
it('Validate the images displayed',() => {
    cy.get('.logo').each(($el) => {
        // $el.css('background-image') => may take some formatting to be just right, depending on what is returned by that function.
        cy.request($el.css('background-image')).then((res) => {
             expect(res.statusCode).to.eql(200);
        });     
    });
});
```